# activity changing in android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-activity

I am making a game for Android, but I never really found a good way to change the activities, or the content views. I have 1 main menu activity now, whose content view receives `MotionEvent`s and dispatches them to my custom buttons. Another `Activity` has a simple `contentView` which just paints the screen in one color. All `contentView`s have the same base class and activity 2 is derived from activity 1.

The problem is, that the app just crashes if a try to change the activity. It takes about 20 seconds, then the error message appears that says the app isnt responding.
In logcat, theres also a message `keyDispatchingTimedOut sending to activity2`
Below is the code for activity change:

```
public void changeActivity() {
    Log.d("changing", "activity");
    Intent i=new Intent(this, Activity_Level.class);
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use context of your activity in method

```
Intent i=new Intent(Youar_Activity_Name.this, Activity_Level.class);
                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

Use above code in your changeActivity() method.

Comment: Note that the code provided by user1563232 does not require such a fix, if the `changeActivity()` method is within the scope of the `Activity`.

Answer (score 1):

if the app isn't responding , it's because you do a long operation on the UI thread . maybe after calling this function you continue to do something else ?

if , as people said , the activity isn't opened (and you can check it by writing to the log inside the onCreate method) , check the manifest.

in any case , if you want to have better control of activities , you can check the possible flags to use for the intents , and you can also use fragments (when possible) , just like google recommends .

Comment: the log in the oncreate method gets printed immediately after processing my input event. after an eternity und several error messages, the other contentview is visible.

Comment: heres the activity: http://pastebin.com/eQjefaWk and the other activity to switch to: http://pastebin.com/KCWkKpgg

Comment: I found out that if I end the updateloop of the mainmenu content view, it works, although it takes a few seconds for such a small contentview class. I end the loop by setting a boolean, then the run method of the thread ends. I thought I dont have to terminate the old activity after starting a new one... I read that the old one is on some stack where the user can simply navigate without reloading... isnt the onPause() method called when another activity comes to the foreground? do I have to do it manually?

Comment: you are on the right direction. for more information of how the activities go from one to another , read both of those links :
http://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the logcat message, I bet you forgot to add the activity in AndroidManifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

I sense that you didn't add all the activities to the `manifest.xml` file. Try to add all the activities there, and give it a run.

Comment: I didnt forget to add the activities in my xml:    <activity
            android:name=".Activity_Level"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
          
        </activity>